# Faster way to get matrix multiplication

Tags: python, distance

I'm trying to calculate `sinc(vec*dist)` over all pairwise distances for each `vec`, where `vec` is a 1D array and `dist` is the pairwise distances of the row vectors in the matrix `coord`. I am using:

```
dist = scipy.spatial.distance.pdist(coord)

for i in range(len(vec)):
    I_avr[i] = numpy.sum(numpy.sinc(vec[i]*dist))
    print vec[i], I_avr[i]
```

Normally `coord` has 10^5 to 10^6 vectors and the length of `vec` is 10^3 to 10^4. Can anyone recommend improvements or changes to make it faster?

Comment: If you can provide some example data, maybe we can help. Maybe [`numpy.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) can help.

Comment: This seems infeasible on a single machine. `dist` is an `O(n^2)` sized array where `n` is at least 10^5. It probably takes at least 5 GB in memory, by no fault of scipy. Have you verified that the code even goes beyond that first line?

Comment: @AlexHall: Thanks for your comment. I do have memory errors computing pdist. Getting the pairwise distances one by one would solve the memory problem but seems inefficient.

Comment: @ChristophTerasa: Here is an example file of the coordinates and `vec = numpy.linspace(5, 90, 1000)`. Thanks! [link](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=548B42CFFAE833D5!246&authkey=!AOc0iYV0BWPNg48&ithint=file%2cdat)

Comment: scipy presumably is computing the distances one by one, I doubt there's a way around that. It probably does it in C which is good but you can still expect it to take a long time to compute 10 billion distances. You probably need a new approach to your bigger problem.

Comment: @AlexHall: I tried in C and it still takes a long time as expected, although faster. Thanks anyway.

Comment: What's the dimension of vectors in `coord`?

Comment: @aldanor: They are simply 3 by 1 vectors, which are atomic coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you could split your distance matrix in chunks and do it block by block and then aggregate, however I don't think this is generally feasible simply because `sum(sinc(...))` is taking too much time. Let's try it with one block of size 10,000:

```py
>>> from scipy.spatial import distance
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.random.seed(0)
>>> coord = np.random.random((10000, 3))
>>> dist = distance.pdist(coord)
>>> %timeit np.sum(np.sinc(dist))
1 loop, best of 3: 1.82 s per loop
```

This is just for one element, and there's no multiplication. If `vec` is of size `10^3` to `10^4`, the time for one `10k x 10k` chunk will be anywhere from 30 minutes to 5.5 hours.

Now, if we increase the size of `coord` to a value from `10^5` to `10^6`, the total elapsed time will be expected to be anywhere from 55 hours to 6.3 years depending on the exact values of inputs.